# How to access a generated XAML item from CS file

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a datagridview **D** filled with lines **L** that contains an expander **E** each,
each line **L** is created from data present in my database
each expander **E** may be filled with a few lines **li** from another table in my database.

When I click one of the lines **li** in the expanders, the selected item will be the original line **L** that contains the expander **E**, so I cannot clearly identify which line **li** I clicked.
I cannot put a name on those lines **li** because they are generated and would all have the same name.

To delete the line **li** or edit some data in it, I put 2 little icons (Ellipses with pictures on them ) and have an "OnMouseLeftButtonUp" event that acts almost as an "OnClick" event.
Once I clicked the ellipse, I would like to access the line **li** and all the data in it, but I don't quite know how to do.

Forgive me in advance, I cannot send any code as some bits of code could be of "confidential" nature

[What I would like to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cym2M.png)

Comment: As a sidenote, even if you have confidential code, it really helps if you can demonstrate a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, I think it would take only 10-15 minutes to throw together a sample app, and show the sort of hierarchy you are using. That said, I'm glad to give whatever insight I can with the information provided.

Comment: I understand this may be hard to get what I would like to do and how to fix the issue without code, I will try to create an example if I have another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can traverse up the backing logical tree to get where you want to go. For example, I have a very similar example where I have an icon embedded within a data grid which captures user interaction. I end up doing something like this in the event handler:

```
(((sender as Image)?.DataContext as DataRecord)?.DataItem as MyViewModelForThisRecord)
```

So without parsing in too much detail the specific scenario you've given, I'd just put a break point in your event handler, and see how you can navigate through the properties it exposes, looking for how you may get to the view model (I'm sure you could sift through documentation to figure this out as well, but I often find that the more direct approach of just inspecting the sender's properties is faster).

All said, you need two things:

1. The view model for the data grid (in my case, this is the DataContext for the view, but I suppose that may not *always* be true)
2. The view model for the record you want to remove. This can generally be found by traversing up the tree.

Then just remove the item (2) from whatever list is being used to populate the data grid (from view model 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I will try it as soon a I can but it might have to wait until next Monday,
I tried doing something else to clear my ideas a bit and got stuck on another problem, so for now I'll try to solve the current issue.
Have a nice day !
I'll mark your answer as accepted if that works for me, don't worry I won't forget

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience. 
In the end, I casted the DataGrid.selectedCell.Item property into a line **L**,
And used the ID contained in that ligne to find it in my database,
then I used some unique properties defining the lines **li** to get where I wanted. 
Solving this issue would have been more simple if i had described my problem properly, but english is not my first language and I struggled a bit to describe my problem.